# How can I check for a consistency constraint which shows users not belonging in an attribute they should be?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

For more detail, I have this question:

All employees that have the same job title must belong to the same department.

For example: All employees that work as Stock Managers belongs to a
department Shipping.
If any of the employees work in the other department with the same job title, the
script must display the violations of the consistency constraint defined above in the
following format.

JOB TITLE | EMPLOYEE ID | DEPARTMENT NAME

Here is a similar statement which is what I am trying to do:

```
SELECT 'Multitable constraint failed,employee' AS "Constraint",   
        enum, 'is not included in either DRIVER or ADMIN tables' AS "Condition"   
FROM EMPLOYEE   
WHERE enumNOT IN (SELECT enum FROM DRIVER)   
AND enum NOT IN (SELECT enumFROM ADMIN);
```

And here is the table that we are given: [Table given](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OLfa4.jpg)

```
SELECT 'All employees that have the same job title must belong to the same department' AS "Constraint", 
employee_id, 'is not in both job title or department' AS "Condition"
FROM EMPLOYEE
WHERE employee_id IN (SELECT job_title 
                      FROM JOB);
AND employee_id NOT IN (SELECT...
```

is what I have so far

Comment: please add the table structure in the qs

Comment: Remove department from this table. Have a separate table of job titles and departments

Comment: We aren't allowed to alter anything that is given to us unfortunately. We can only answer the questions given.

Comment: So you want to group by job title and department having more than one record?

Comment: How do you know which job title belongs to which department?

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the list of job titles that are used in multiple departments:

```
SELECT
  job_title, count(1)
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT
    job_title, department_name
  FROM employee
  ) a
GROUP BY job_title
HAVING count(1) > 1
```